# Liquibase: How do I drop a function if it exists

Tags: sql-server, liquibase

I want to remove a SQL scalar function if it exists in my database. We are using SQL server 2014.

If I try the following script:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog" xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.5.xsd">  
    <changeSet context="schema" author="myself" id="1">
        <comment>Drop Function MyFunction</comment>
        <sql endDelimiter="\nGO">
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects where name = N'MyFunction' AND Type = N'FN') DROP FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction
GO
        </sql>      
    </changeSet>    
</databaseChangeLog>
```

I receive the following message :

> Unexpected error running Liquibase: Lexical error at line 1, column
>   105. Encountered: "\u00a0" (160), after : ""

I checked the SQL syntax in Management Studio and it worked fine.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried running it without endDelimiter?

Comment: I removed the endDelimiter and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `endDelimiter` from `<sql>`:

```
<changeSet context="schema" author="myself" id="1">
    <comment>Drop Function MyFunction</comment>
    <sql>
        IF EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects where name = N'MyFunction' AND Type = N'FN')
        DROP FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction GO
    </sql>      
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects where name = 'MyFunction' AND Type = 'FN') 
begin
 DROP FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow these steps.

1. check the condition
2. if expectedResult is 1, execute the next
3. creating your function.

```xml
    <changeSet author="myself" id="1">
        <!--check the condition-->
        <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
            <sqlCheck expectedResult="1">SELECT COUNT(*)
                                         FROM information_schema.routines
                                         WHERE routine_name = 'MyFunction'
                                           AND routine_type = 'FUNCTION'
                                           AND routine_schema = 'your_schema'</sqlCheck>
        </preConditions>
        <!--if expectedResult is 1, execute the next <sql>-->
        <sql>
        <![CDATA[
            DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS your_schema.MyFunction;
            ]]>
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
    <changeSet author="myself" id="2">
        <!--creating your function-->

        <sql dbms="mysql" splitStatements="true" endDelimiter="//">
            CREATE FUNCTION MyFunction(param1 VARCHAR (36)) RETURNS INT
                DETERMINISTIC
            BEGIN
        DECLARE ....
        </sql>
    </changeSet>
```